# Editing Normals To Define the Solidify Modifier

Tags: python, mesh, modifiers, normals

below is a picture of a shell after the solidify modifier has been added.

Is there a way to edit the normals individually to make the slot parallel?

Preferably in the python API. (note: I am already able to select each individual point already)

Thank you! I've been stuck on this all day

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you add a diagram to show what you are trying to achieve ? Also the state of the mesh before applying the modifier :)

Comment: hi Gorgious, I ended up using a boolean approach with the new exact function in 2.9, thank you for your response!